# How do you return the value from a public void?

Tags: java, static-methods

How do you return the value from a public void? This is what a segment of my code looks like:

```
public void divide(int op, double numbers1, double numbers2, int answer, double nums) {
    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    
    if (op == 4) {
        nums = (numbers1 / numbers2);
        System.out.println("What is the answer to " + numbers1 + "/" + numbers2 + "?");
        answer = scan.nextInt();

        if (nums == answer)
            System.out.println("You're Correct!");
        else
            System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer is: " + df2.format(nums));
    }
}
```

I would like to return this value back to the main method, but am not sure how to (like do I have to put a statement of this method back to my main method or something, also do I need a return value here).

Comment: Why is the method `void` if you want to return a value?

Comment: At the same time we should expect OP to have done some basic research before asking so this is really a borderline case for me. We don’t want stackoverflow to be drowned in basic questions about how or assign values to a variables or what `new` is etc

Answer (score 4):

Making a method `void` *tells* the compiler that there is no return value.  If you want there to be a return value, your method cannot be `void`.

Instead, you might want your return type to be `String`, with the message that would print to `System.out`.

Comment: Or `boolean` in this case.